# Angular 14 Resize Observable not triggering

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

It is not triggering at all, the console log doesn't print and the this.widht doesn't change.

```
constructor(private host: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.width$.next(entries[0].contentRect.width);         
      console.log('width', width);
    });
  });

  this.observer.observe(this.host.nativeElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a ViewChild to populate this.host ElementRef: https://medium.com/@anooprvarrier/angular-elementref-interface-c826cd5db732